# Disrespect to Sahab's names? Is this tolerable?

Tags: discussion

I understand one can ask question about Shia sect or Sunni sect for believes just to understand their point of view. I think it is good to expand our knowledge. The problem comes when our respected sahabas are not properly saluted at this question [Why did Ayesha battle with Ali (a.s) in the Battle of the Camel (Jamal)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2397/why-did-ayesha-battle-with-ali-a-s-in-the-battle-of-the-camel-jamal). Further [In this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2403/88), the answer says

> First, to give you a complete idea about the situation, what were
> Ayesha, Talha and Zubair doing? Where where they?

Without even reading further, I can see see there has been some disrespect towards the sahaba name. They should have been addressed as **Ayesha(RA),Talha(RA),Zubair(RA)**

What should be the rule here. One sect is clearly disrespecting the other and in my opinion not tolerable to Sunni Muslims.

I will be able to accept any answer that resolves this matter in some light.

Comment: I'm reminded of the treaty with the Meccans, where the prophet willingly struck out the phrase "Messenger of Allah" just because the Meccans didn't believe it.  As long as it's not outright derogatory, I don't see the problem.

Comment: :O Take it easy, man, and please read further. I meant no disrespect, and I love all sahabas. But, I am not used to discussing Islam in English :/ .. I would never dream to say Ayesha without (Radiyah-Allah-o Anha) in my life... I hope that's clear... please don't assume disrespect so quickly...

Comment: (My member since is ... Today! :'( ) [btw, reading your title to this topic made me feel so angry to the point that I felt "I'd kill that guy who meant disrespect!" .. only to see that you meant me ....

Comment: I just wanted to raise this issue, as long as we agree on something, I am ok with that.

Comment: Last Note: This site is even more serious than SO! I mean, OK things should be professional and stuff in all SE sites, but ultimately we are brothers seeking the truth and helping each other. This is religion we are discussing, unlike strict theories and laws.. It's only natural to be more friendly :) .. Either ways, I admit that I don't belong here... I wish you all the best.

Comment: @Mazyod if you see my posts, You will see that I am very broad minded myself. This is not about scaring someone. This is about setting rules. As you can see, no one edited your post. I just raised a concern. And why I raised it,because I have seen a lot worse in real life and I just didn't want to bring that here.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that .. I agree. I had a really bad first day here with a lot of criticism, and I interpreted your post badly. I should view your question as, "What if anyone did that?".. my bad.

Comment: That's right right. It was a general question.

Answer (score 4):

As stated countless times before, this site isn't an *Islamic* one. We should expect people from all denominations here, and some of them (perhaps many I would venture) do not hold the respect that Sunni Muslims hold for the Sahaba.

No I'm not condoning outright name calling and slander, but dropping an RA (or it's proper long form equivalent) is to be expected and further more should be tolerated.

Answer (score 2):

It's funny this should pop up now. I've never used (RA) or (SAWS) when mentioning their names in text.

I was told that it did not count as a du'a when written in short form. Can't find a reference to that (maybe it would make a good question?) but any real Islamic publisher usually go to lengths to write the full arabic script in books.

If so, it becomes unnecessary. It's a character limited world, so I avoid it in SMS, comments, titles.

In a similar sense to gifts, I feel it's unfair to give some to some people and then not give it to others, so I avoid using the salutations at all.

And in another sense, the Shia' are based around having a low opinion of Abu Bakr r.a. and other sahaba, so it may be seen as an insult to them to use the salutations.

This may not be proper practice, but it is an approach to the situation, and you can just downvote this answer accordingly if it's considered rude.